# Routing error when using nested resources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, nested-resources

I have a Post and Comment models. Comment belongs to a Post, and it is nested under Post in routes. Comments are posted from Posts#show. My routes look like this:

```
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments, only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  end
```

If a user submits a comment that fails validation, the URL will look like this:

```
app.com/posts/:id/comments
```

If, for any reason, the user decides to hit enter in the address bar, there will be a routing error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/posts/21/comments"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

This strikes me as some what odd. I understand why the error is happening, but it doesn't seem like it's a good idea for usability. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

This becomes a bigger issue when doing friendly redirects. When a friendly redirect happens, Rails will redirect to that same URL using a GET request, again causing a routing error.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way to avoid it is to create a route for this case and redirect to wherever make sense for your application. Something like the following:

```
match "/posts/:id/comments" => redirect {|params| "/posts/#{params[:id]}" }
```

Instead of that routing error, the user would be redirected to the post page.

Comment: Interesting, what about in the case of a post request, or a user submission, is there a way to preserve the params and continue with post submission?

Comment: You can store the params in a cookie. Also you'd have to control whether you have to retrieve the stored data or not to try the submission again.

Answer (score 1):

If your routes are

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments, only: [:create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
end
```

then the URL for edit would be

```
app.com/posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit
```

where :id is the comment.  If validation fails, you should be redirecting back to this URL.

```
def update
  @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])

  if @comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
    redirect_to(edit_post_path(@post))
  else
    redirect_to(edit_post_comment_path(@post, @comment), :notice => "update failed")
  end
end
```

Better, since you are already at the correct edit URL,

```
...
  else
    flash[:error] = "Error - could not update comment"
    render :action => "edit"
  end
```

Comment: Just to be clear, your example `update` method, is do you mean this is in the posts controller or the comments controller?

Comment: I should have included the class name.  It's the comments controller.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best but the other solution may be to add comments through nested attributes of post.